# Is it possible to update the contact info (FN/LN, OU, Organization,..) of a certificate?

Tags: certificates, x.509

When creating a self-signed certificate you are asked to enter some information (First Name, Last Name, Organization Unit, Organization, City, State,...). Is it possible to update any of those fields later? (E.g. my company changed its legal name and now I want to update the "Organization" name to reflect the new one.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, if you changed those informations on the certificate, the fingerprint changed, and the signature is invalid.

You will need to issue a new certificate.

Comment: Are all fields used for fingerprinting?

Comment: Yes, all those fields are used for the fingerprint.

Answer (score 17):

I like to compare certificates to driver's licenses. Can you take a sharpie and change the First Name, Last Name, Address on your driver's license? No, you need to contact the government and get a new license printed.

Slightly less sassily, a certificate is basically a signed statement from a trusted 3rd party (the CA) that says "This public key belongs to this person". All the fields you mention (First Name, Last Name, Organization Unit, Organization, City, State,...) are part of "this person". If you were able to freely modify these fields without the consent or knowledge of the CA, then that would completely defeat the purpose of a certificate.

Comment: Not the best analogy. In Germany they actually just put small stickers over the address of your ID card or the issue date on your drivers licence, instead of printing new ones. They use a ballpoint pen to write the issue date though, not a sharpie.

Comment: @kapex HAHA! Really? Not very secure ;)

Comment: Yes really. The stickers have _some_ security features like the same fine printed background patterns as the IDs and probably use some special material. You probably can get them of without destroying them. But they aren't as durable as the cards - the issue date on my driver's licence has worn of completely by now.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write "You probably **can't** get them of without destroying them."

Comment: @kapex Perhaps I should use "passport" instead of "driver's license" when I use this analogy? Except that, in North America at least, almost every adult has a driver's license and uses it routinely as ID, but many people have never left their country and therefore never needed to get a passport.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: or an Identity Card, a common thing in the EU. More common than passports as it i usually issued for free, and allows for inter-EU travel.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer, as usual.  To put it another way - if it was possible to change the identifying information on a certificate this easily, without breaking the signature - then what would stop an attacker from getting a CA-signed certificate in his name, then changing the name to paypal.com, then using it to MITM Paypal?

Comment: I went to university with someone from Nebraska, USA. Her driving licence from home was literally a bit of typewriter'd cardstock with a photo pasted in the corner. Then it was laminated. I presume this is why you created "Real ID."

Answer (score 4):

No, changing any field in the certificate will break the signature. You need to get a new certificate with the updated info. This is exactly like asking the question "I have a certificate for rsc.com, can I just change it to say it's for google.com?".

In the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1), all the fields of a certificate are in a structure called "to be signed certificate", with the signature added.

Comment: It is not exactly the same as asking that question because it could be that  some fields could be changed while others don't.

Comment: All the fields are signed.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers correctly point out that strictly speaking, there is no way to modify a certificate, that's not the end of the story.

A certificate comprises three components:

- Public key
- Name (Subject, possibly SubjectAltNames as well)
- Signature binding the former two together

While there is no way to change the name without replacing the signature as well, that doesn't mean you can't reuse the key pair. You can just take the old key pair and reissue a certificate with a new name. This might simplify handling of the reissued certificate. (This is also one way to handle renewals of expiring certificates.)

Depending on the application, you can take it a bit further and reuse most of the information from the old certificate, for example the validity dates and the serial. However, this still might not make make the two certificates completely interchangeable, because the Issuer name will change anyway when self-signing.

Comment: There's another complication though: how the client (or whatever) is configured to trust that self-signed certificate. Even if you issue a new cert with the same public key, it generally won't be automatically trusted under the same policy as the old one (because its fingerprint changed, or something similar).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Right, that's why I wrote it _might_ simplify things. It's probably not too useful for CA and server certs (or authentication in general) due to the trust anchor issues you mentioned. It does help for client certs, S/MIME and the like, where it's good that the "new" keypair can still decrypt everything encrypted to the old one.